# PyQt5 - Identificar que pressionou F10 em um QLineEdit

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt-5

Como faço para abrir uma função ao pressionar a tecla F10 em um QLineEdit?

Pesquisando encontrei a função **"returnPressed"** mas só funciona para a tecla "Enter"

```
class Ui_MainWindow(object):
def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
    MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
    MainWindow.resize(612, 430)
    self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
    self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
    self.lin1 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lin1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 130, 113, 20))
    self.lin1.setObjectName("lin1")
    self.lin2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lin2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(150, 130, 113, 20))
    self.lin2.setObjectName("lin2")
    self.lin3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lin3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(290, 130, 113, 20))
    self.lin3.setObjectName("lin3")
    self.lin4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
    self.lin4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(430, 130, 113, 20))
    self.lin4.setObjectName("lin4")
    MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)

    # -----------------------------------------------------------------
    self.lin1.returnPressed.connect(self.teste)
    # -----------------------------------------------------------------

    self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
    QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

def teste(self):
    print('Tecla ENTER pressionada')

def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
    _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
    MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
```

Comment: Excelente resposta Guilherme, era exatamente o que estava procurando!

Comment: Olá Rafael. Não use o campo "Sua resposta" para agradecer, você "agradecer" marcando a resposta como correta, clicando no icone ✓ que fica do lado da minha resposta. Se tiver duvidas siga as dicas de: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/1079/3635

Answer (score 0):

Use o `PyQt5.QtWidgets.QShortcut` com `PyQt5.QtGui.QKeySequence('F10')` ou com o atalho `PyQt5.QtCore.Qt.Key_F10`

Note que para executar o atalho somente no widget especifico é necessário informar o contexto, o evento será executado em qualquer parte do programa (contexto `WindowShortcut`).

Para especificar o contexto como sendo o próprio `QLineEdit` defina no atributo:

```
context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut
```

Dessa forma:

```
PyQt5.QtWidgets.QShortcut(<atalho>, <widget>, <evento>, context=QtCore.Qt.WidgetShortcut)
```

Um exemplo bem simples com dois campos de texto com funções diferentes:

```
from sys import argv, exit
from PyQt5.QtCore import Qt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QLabel, QLineEdit, QMessageBox, QShortcut, QVBoxLayout, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QKeySequence


class Examplo(QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Examplo, self).__init__()

        self.textEdit1 = QLineEdit()
        self.textEdit2 = QLineEdit()

        QShortcut(Qt.Key_F10, self.textEdit1, self.eventoFoo, context=Qt.WidgetShortcut)
        QShortcut(Qt.Key_F10, self.textEdit2, self.eventoBar, context=Qt.WidgetShortcut)

        mainLayout = QVBoxLayout()

        mainLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Primeiro label F10"))
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit1)

        mainLayout.addWidget(QLabel("Segundo label F10"))
        mainLayout.addWidget(self.textEdit2)

        self.setLayout(mainLayout)

        self.setWindowTitle("Exemplo")


    def eventoFoo(self):
        msg = QMessageBox(self)
        msg.setText("#1 eventoFoo() executado")
        msg.show()


    def eventoBar(self):
        msg = QMessageBox(self)
        msg.setText("#2 eventoBar() executado")
        msg.show()


app = QApplication(argv)
exemplo = Examplo()
exemplo.show()
exit(app.exec_())
```